# What is the fastest way to work with ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a little bit confused about what is the fastest and the friendly way with the server to request POST or GET from server by AJAX, is it jQuery (`$.load()`, `$.get()`, `$.post()`, `$.ajax()`) or Javascript like XMLHttpRequest?

I need to make a function or class to use in my project to call request from server via AJAX, but I don't know what is the faster and more friendly with the server jQuery or Javascript.

Comment: `.load`, `.get` and `.post` are all just shorthand for `.ajax` which is just a wrapper for `XMLHttpRequest`.  So, they're all the same.

Answer (score 6):

> is it jquery $.load() , $.get() , $.post() , $.ajax()

Those functions are all quasi-synonyms of each other; jQuery adds some syntactic sugar and a standardized interface, but in the end, it uses the browser's native Ajax engine (like `XMLHttpRequest`). I don't think there are notable performance differences between any of them.

There *may* be super-intensive edge cases with thousands of requests where using the "raw" browser engine could shave off a few milliseconds here or there, but for the majority of cases, it won't matter.

You can most likely use jQuery's functions (or those of another library if you need to) without even thinking about performance for a long, long while. A lot of big names use jQuery heavily, [including Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65321/what-technologies-were-used-to-build-the-chat) for their [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @Sinetheta that's why I said *quasi-* synonyms :) They all serve a different purpose, but in the end, they end up with one and the same handler.

Comment: thank you very much for your advice but what is quasi-synonyms  ? i didn't understand it :$

Comment: @Jack they provide different ways to start an Ajax request ($.post presets `method: POST`, $.get presets `method: GET` etc.) but in the end, they all use the same central function. They're not real synonyms of each other because they do slightly different things.

Answer (score 4):

`.load()`, `$.get()`, `$.post()` and `$.getJSON()` for that matter, are all just short-cuts for `$.ajax()`. They are just `$.ajax()` with some of the settings pre-determined for you.

The only thing unique about `.load()` is that it already has a success handler defined for you which injects the retrieved content into your current target.

They are all equally fast, the only question is which you find most readable.

If you will be making numerous similar ajax calls then it is best to use [$.ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) in an accessible place (read: near top). This allows you to pre-set your most common settings, thereby creating your own short-cut function.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery just wraps XMLHttpRequest and standardizes the interface for you across all browsers. There's a little overhead, but none on the network side of things. I'd go as far as saying that the overhead of jQuery's functions is trivial when comparing it to the amount of time you're going to save yourself having to standardize the XMLHttpRequest across browsers yourself.

Otherwise your speed is determined by the server's bandwidth, the clients connecting to your server, amount of traffic, speed/optimization of backend code etc. etc.

Comment: thank you , for your advice i know the speed depend on server  , but at the end what you recommended using jquery or javascript ? i iam working on social project so its has allot of ajax request

Comment: I'd recommend using a framework, like jQuery, over straight-up XMLHttpRequest, since it abstracts all the cross-browser problems for you. It's proven, it's fast, it's what you need.

Comment: you mean of framework like hidden iframe ? , i just make a research about iframe and XMLHttpRequest and most of people said XMLHttpRequest is faster and better becouse its send only the size of data you request from server

Comment: I mean framework as a library/bundle of code that abstracts things for you. jQuery is a JavaScript framework, as is YUI, mootools, sencha etc. They're all libraries that achieve different things built on JavaScript. I do not mean iframes.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery **is** javascript. All the ajax functions you described rely on XMLHttpRequest (or its alternatives in older browsers), so they will be slower than using the browser's functionality directly.

The tradeoff is, of course, that jQuery's functions are easier to use. So, if it's efficiency that is your first concern, write your own ajax function (or use ajax directly). If you just want to get it done then using jQuery will be quicker.

Comment: thanks skier , so if i make my own javascript class to define the browser and handle the request with browser function this well be more faster and better than jquery right ?

Comment: Yes, a little bit. The significant gain would be that the user doesn't have to download and initialize jQuery.

Comment: @Jack no, not by any seriously measurable value. (@skier you have a point re downloading jQuery though. But arguably, if you use the CDN, it is preloaded on the vast majority of clients)

Comment: Right. The actual execution of that function won't likely be any better, assuming you implement a cross-browser solution. Depending on if you use CDN to include jQuery, some (or many) users may already have a cached copy of jQuery. Also: there are small libraries just for Ajax; you could use one of those instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Yes, a CDN is great, and I might even go so far as to agree that it is likely to be cached. But what people forget is that jQuery is NOT a lightweight library, and that it has to be re-initialized on every page load. It takes a long time to execute 90kb of minified javascript - in fact, many optimization tools tag jQuery as a long-running script and suggest you remove it.

Comment: As for the small ajax libraries, I certainly agree. But for many applications these are overkill as well. I mostly reuse a function I wrote a while ago, which provides everything my web apps have used in under 1kb (the reason I even have a function is to cache request objects, as well as make the syntax nicer/shorter).

Comment: @skier88 I think it's important to take into account the context in which these optimization tools are evaluating scripts. If YOU had written a 90kb script to do "a thing", I would wonder just what the hell was going on in there. But what we're talking about is a magical cross-browser internet fix. Are there better, more focussed solutions to any given problem? Of course. But I think the best general rule is: if you don't know whether or not jquery is right for you, jquery is right for you ;)

Comment: you guys are awesome , what is the CDN ? lol , i just start to make my own javascript class to cross over all the browsers , and i think its well be fast than jquery , i had notice that jquery has allot of functions i don't want it inside the jquery file , and most of them for effect's like slideDown animate blaa blaa blaa , so i think ill make my own effect inside the class and create another class for some effects this well be better ri8 !

Comment: @skier do you have hard numbers on how long initializing jQuery actually takes per page load? My suspicion is that modern browsers are optimizing and caching the hell out of that process, too.

Comment: @Sinetheta I guess it depends on what you want. If "right for you" means "provides a robust solution as quickly as possible", then I agree. But at the same time, jQuery obfuscates the details of javascript, and makes it impossible to obtain a deeper understanding of the language through experience. So, for some people, I would agree that jQuery is the answer. But Jack seems interested in writing an efficient solution, as well as learning more about this language.

Comment: @JackKFouani a CDN is a Content Distribution Network. It basically means that you don't link to a copy of jQuery on your server, you link to a copy at a Google (or other provider's) url. There are two main benefits: first, a lot of people use CDNs. So clients visiting your website may already have the script at that url in their cache, so they don't have to load it again. And second, a CDN is not a single server but a network of servers in different locations; requests for a url on a CDN will be answered by the server nearest the requesting computer, thus speeding up response time.

Comment: @Pekka Using "Page Speed Test" for chrome I'm consistently getting around 270ms to initialized a cached file. That's on an older netbook, so most computers are probably faster, but cell phones are probably still slower. Also, I'm not sure how a browser could cache an initialized jQuery object, since every page (=page load) has to be sandboxed, and the object is free to change state after it's been initialized. The fact that in my testing the first initialization took about as long as the rest seems to support this.

Comment: @skier interesting, that would be a lot.